# Can you append the elements of one list to those of another without iterating through the lists in Q?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to add the elements of one list to another with the desired output as seen below.

I've attempted joining the lists with the `,` operator but this does not create the desired results:

```
q)l1: (1 2 3; 5 6 7)
q)l2: (4 8)
q)l1,l2
(1 2 3; 5 6 7;4;8)
```

Desired result: `(1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8)`

I'm wondering if there's any built-in ability to do this in q as my understanding is that having to iterate through these vectors would be inefficient in q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing the following which will join each element of the left with each element of the right

```
q)l1: (1 2 3; 5 6 7)
q)l2:(4 8)

q)l1,'l2
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Thanks very much Kevin!  For anyone else who may be new to q I found some information on this single quote operator here: https://code.kx.com/v2/basics/syntax/